# Output comment in a macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to have a set of macros that declares things like this one:

```
#define DECL_ITEM( var_name, type, array, flags, comment )  \
        type    var_name array,     ///< comment
```

Unfortunately, the preprocessor will strip away `///< comment`.
Is there any trick to make my macro output the variable declaration along with its comment?

I expect that

```
DECL_ITEM( var1, int, [ 10 ], 0, "What var1 stands for." )
```

output to be like:

```
int var1[ 10 ], ///< What var1 stands for.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why?  Do you plan on spending a substantial amount of time looking at the preprocessed source?  (And if so, why?)

Comment: I plan to output this preprocessed file so that other projects will use it. I need to update an index, metainformation and database-like structure and the error prone work of having to ensure consistency on 3 ends is not what I call wise.

Comment: Why are you generating to a preprocessed file instead of just using the original source file?  (Regardless of the answer to this question, the preprocessor is not the right tool for this job.)

Comment: So you plan to use the preprocessor as a code generator?

Comment: Yes @fljx. I want to use the preprocessor to generate a ".c" and a ".h" file that will then be compiled into a binary. This is the why, but I rather have an answer to my question instead of wandering about my "whys", if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Since the preprocessor isn't the way, maybe the "whys" help find alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your idea, but suggest you to use a script lamguage like PHP as your code generator instead of CPP.

An example would be:

```
class   MetaInfo
{
    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $arr_w;
    public $flags;
    public $comment;

    public function __construct( $n, $t, $a, $f, $c )
    {
        $this->name     = $n;
        $this->type     = $t;
        $this->arr_w    = $a;
        $this->flags    = $f;
        $this->comment  = $c;
    }
};

function decl_db( $db_defs )
{
echo '
struct dataBase
{
';
    foreach( $db_defs as $def )
    {
        if ( $def->arr_w == "" )
            $decl="\t$def->type $def->name;             ///< $def->comment\n";
        else
            $decl="\t$def->type $def->name[ $def->arr_w ];      ///< $def->comment\n";
        print $decl;
    }
echo '
};
';
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Custom DB definitions.

$db_defs = array(
    new MetaInfo( "var1",   "int",  "10",   "0",    "What var1 stands for." ),
);


decl_db( $db_defs );
```

And it should output:

```
struct dataBase
{
    int var1[ 10 ], ///< What var1 stands for.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor is not intended to operate in any environment other than the input phase of the compiler, so does not provide for capabilities like that which are only meaningful for standalone use.